# PDFtk on RHEL 5.6

Tags: rhel, pdf, pdftk

My colleagues and I are trying to install PDFtk on a RHEL 5.6 server. PDFtk requires libgcj which is installed, but an older version (v4.1.2)

When we install PDFtk and try to add a password to a PDF we get the error:

```
Unhandled Java Exception in create_output():
ExceptionConverter: Unhandled Java Exception in main():
Aborted
```

We tried upgrading the libgcj but that didn't work and didn't want to push harder because we didn't want break anything beyond repair.

We were looking into qpdf but it doesn't seem to be supported on RHEL 5.6. To make matters worse, our yum seems to be broken because it used to point to an old Satellite server that is no longer available.

The ultimate goal is to be able to encrypt PDFs on the server. Any...ANY help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check the EPEL repositories, you might find it there.

Comment: Thanks for the response @vonbrand
We did find in the repositories and downloaded it it couldn't install because of conflicts.
Eventually, we purchased a standalone tool.